# How to disable aws codepipeline trigger for every code check-in

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I am working on AWS CodePipeline , Actually, I had an existing AWS Codepipeline setup for 3 pipeline jobs. We are using Bitbucket for source code provider, In codepipeline we had established a connection between Bitbucket repo to codepipeline access. Now all pipeline every code checkin in pipeline is executing. Now I want to disable these auto-trigger pipelines. we need to execute all pipeline manually. Please help with this.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have provided very little details. But assuming CodeCommit as your repo, you can delete/modify CW rule that triggers the CodePipeline.

Comment: Were you able to sort this out ? Looking for the same now (disable bitbucket auto trigger)

Answer (score 3):

To disable the AWS Codepipeline trigger for every code check in bitbucket, you have go to the SOURCE configuration (the bitbucket configuration) of your code pipeline, there will be a WebHook checkbox you will have to uncheck it.

[image: Disable the BitBucket Trigger in CodePipeline[]

You can start the pipeline manually both in CLI or console

cli:

```
aws codepipeline start-pipeline-execution --name MyFirstPipeline
```

console:

1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the CodePipeline console at http://console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/codepipeline/home.
2. In Name, choose the name of the pipeline you want to start.
3. On the pipeline details page, choose Release change. This starts the most recent revision available in each source location specified in a source action through the pipeline.

For more details:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-rerun-manually.html

Comment: Are you sure the webhook option is available for bitbucket ? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Did you find  the answer?

Comment: I cannot find any similar option for CodeCommit. Seems that it is not possible to have pipelines in CodePipeline to not start automatically if the source is CodeCommit?